# how to can get values in facts in clips?

Tags: return-value, clips

how to can get values in facts in clips?

```
CLIPS> (assert(rule1 (read)))
4
==> f-1     (rule1 1)
```

I want the fact 1 is stored in a variable and do calculations.

In this example, I want to return a value of ' 4 '.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CLIPS> (watch facts)
CLIPS> (assert (rule1 (read)))
4
==> f-1     (rule1 4)
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> 
(defrule double
   (rule1 ?v)
   =>
   (printout t "Twice the value is " (* 2 ?v) crlf))
CLIPS> (agenda)
0      double: f-1
For a total of 1 activation.
CLIPS> (run)
Twice the value is 8
CLIPS>
```